# ClassNotFoundException - ResteasyBootstrap

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, resteasy

Upon running my GWT/GAE (App Engine) application the app throws this error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
```

Here is the POM.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the log:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:213)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)    at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1101)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:630)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureWebApp(WebXmlConfiguration.java:180)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1247)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)    at
>   org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:205)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:232)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

What could be missing?

**Update:**

Anyone can share their web.xml that worked for RestEasy + GAE

Comment: Which version of resteasy-jaxrs jar are u using and check for version 2.3.0.GA or higher.

Comment: version 2.3.5.Final
Apparently, the JARS are not being copied into the WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: This link solved my problem,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494722/getting-classnotfoundexception-resteasybootstrap-and-classnotfoundexception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception indicates the classes are not there.

Ensure that resteasy-jaxrs are copied into your WEB-INF/lib and also ensure that your version is 2.3.0.GA or higher.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is maven base project then run

mvn eclipse:clean

mvn eclipse:eclipse

it will add jar from m2 repo to lib folder then redeploy webapp and restart tomcat/server

Answer (score 0):

Please check that

1. You are not pointing to a JRE, should be a JDK.
2. Remove and Add your server. Then run the application again.